# HTML Input AJAX Updating - add style to input field using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working my way through some changes to an html form to perform an AJAX update when a user exits a field. I'm new to Javascript and AJAX so still working out syntax issues as I go but I've managed to get to the point where the user exits a field and a PHP page is called which updates the database.

I'm now on to the final part which is making a change based on success or failure to let the user know what happened. I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap 3 framework so would like to leverage some of the available styles for success and failure, namely the following validations states:

```
.has-success
.has-error
```

Here's the html input that triggers the AJAX call from when the user exits this field:

Manager

I'm not sure how to add a new class for success or failure of the AJAX call, and also if I need to display an error message how I can also incorporate that.

Here's the Javascript that calls the PHP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editProject(storeManager,uuid) {
   // Allocate an XMLHttpRequest object
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
      // IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   // Set up the readyState change event handler
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ((this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200)) {
         document.getElementById("storeManager").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   // Open an asynchronous POST connection and send request
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "editProject.php", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send("storeManager="+storeManager+"&id="+uuid);

}
</script>
```

I gather this is the line I need to modify for the success option:

```
document.getElementById("storeManager").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

but not sure what the syntax would be, and then how to have a failure option (e.g. if the database update returns an error).

Comment: It doesn't really seem like you have tried anything yourself. Have you searched around to look at how to handle failed requests? Or are you trying to return a custom error from your PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap, which requires jQuery, why not make life a bit easier on yourself and use jQuery to perform your Ajax request instead of (what I would consider) the old way?

*For Example:*

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <!-- all of your form stuff -->
    <input id="storeManager" type="text">
    ...
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "editProject.php",
    data: storeManager: storeManager, uuid: uuid,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-error");
    }
});
</script>
```

I haven't tested this but if you [have a look at some online examples](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/the-perfect-jquery-ajax-request/) you should be able to pick this syntax up pretty quickly, especially if you were able to work out what you already have above.